# this.$firebase is undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm building my first Vue.js app, trying to use `vuex` with `vuexfire`.

```
//main.js
import firebase from 'firebase';

...

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);

...

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('setDealsRef');
    },
  });
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('/signin');
  } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

And:

```
//store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { firebaseMutations } from 'vuexfire';

...

Vue.use(Vuex);

const db = this.$firebase.firestore();
const dealsRef = db.collection('deals');
```

And:

```
//store/mutations.js
export default {
  SET_USER(state) {
    state.user = this.$firebase.auth().currentUser;
  },
...
}
```

This complies OK, but throws `TypeError: this.$firebase is undefined[Learn More]` in the console.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I think I've read every relevant tutorial and StackOverflow questions, and tried everything.

Comment: What did `[Learn More]` reveal?

Comment: It's just the regular Mozilla docs on `undefined`

Comment: Ah, that's not much help.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```js
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

You add `$firebase` to the Vue instance. So for

```js
this.$firebase
```

to work, the `this` should be a Vue insteance. In other words, that line must execute **inside** a Vue method/hook/computed/etc.

And the code you show, doesn't do that:

```js
const db = this.$firebase.firestore();
```

in the code above, the `this` is the outer context. (Probably is `window`.)

So for it to work outside a Vue instance, you **have to do**:

```js
const db = Vue.prototype.$firebase.firestore();
```

Provided the line above executes **after** (in time/order) the line where you initialize the `$firebase`.

Comment: That just changes the error to `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_vue__.default.prototype.$firebase is undefined`

Comment: I think the core problem is firebase isn't initialized when it gets called in store.js and components. I can't figure out how to wait for it.

Comment: How can I first initialize firebase, only _then_ run routes.js and everything else?

Comment: Place the `Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);` line as "close to the top" as possible in your `main.js` file, so it executes before anything else.

Comment: Can you expand your `main.js` code in the question? Show where `store.js` is imported. Also expand your `store.js`, show where `store` is defined and exported.

Comment: store.js is loaded inside main.js... I think I solved the problem - see my answer. I'm still getting some other errors, will confirm once those are solved, but should be unrelated.

Comment: I had a different, but similar, idea. Let me know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem:

1. Moving firebase initialization to store.js
2. Changing `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {` to `Vue.prototype.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {` in main.js
3. Importing firebase as: `import firebase from '@firebase/app';
   import '@firebase/firestore';`